# sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer ignores RemoteCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to fix an existing .Net 2.0 service/application.

It's a TCP server that accepts SSL/TLS connections. Operates over port 443, as expected. It is used to respond to Yealink provisioning requests. You can pop the url in the phone, and it will get the settings etc (anyway not important.)

The problem is that when older phones request this service it works fine, but now, since the new versions of the phones, it does not work.

This is the code that fials:

```
using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications)))
{
    X509Certificate c = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "XXXX");
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(c, false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

    // Process request etc
}
```

and this is the "AcceptAllCertifications"

```
private bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, X509Certificate certification, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

New phones cause the app to produce an error on sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(...);

> System.componentmodel.win32exception: the certificate chain was issued
>   by an authority that is not trusted.

Is, "the certificate" they mention here my certificate (one on server) or their certificate (one sent from phone)?

I have no idea (and will never have any idea) about the kind of certificate sent by the users phone.

The certificate "cert.pfx" (my certificate) was bought from DigiCert, (its a wildcard certificate). It was exported with a password, and oh yea, did i mention this works absolutely fine with all regular browsers and older phones... just not the Yealink's new phones.

How do i just skip the entire authentication thing, i just want it to work, its not a public system? With the new phones the "RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications)" is never called, i have followed this with the debugger, its skipped out completely.

Edit:
[image: Certificate Checker]

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the phones don't like the server-side certificate that you are presenting to them and stop the SSL handshake. This could happen if they don't know about DigiCert's root CA certificate. Could you use Wireshark on the server to analyze the SSL handshake? That would tell you, which side interrupts the handshake.

Comment: Actually... you are spot on. The phones have this setting "Only Accept Trusted Certificates", that seems to be Enabled by default. I have reliably create and prevent this error now. Of course, this is a real pain, because i now have to un-box each of the phones and toggle this setting... how annoying!

Comment: Before you do that, I would try to get a list of trusted root certificates from those phones. You might be able to buy a certificate that derives from a trusted root certificate that is already present on your Yeaklink phones.

Comment: I've just take a brand new phone out of the stock room, and booted it up. There are no root certificates and the "Only Accept Trusted Certificates" is enabled. So basically HTTPS is out of the question. Thanks christoph for the help tho.

Comment: After some more digging i noticed that Yealink say "Yealink IP phones trust the following CAs by default:"... and in the list is: "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA". Its close, but not exactly the same, the certificate i have exported is using "DigiCert Global Root CA", could i export it using the High Assurance CA? if so how?

Comment: Hmm, "High Assurance" sounds like a root CA for those premium certificates, for which you pay more and I believe they also really verify your business (not just accept an admin email address). I would contact DigiCert and ask whether they can create a certificate for you signed by that root CA, and at what cost. Or check if you can use another certificate company whose root CA is in the trusted list.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the Digicert Checker and ran it against my app. Its shows the "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA", but only as a second chain to the "DigiCert High Assurance EV CA-1". I think ill have to get this swapped out by Digicert so that it shows:
Subject=(OUR_CERTIFICATE), Issuer=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA ===> Subject=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, Issuer=Baltimore CyberTrust Root. Not so?

Comment: Just reread your entire post. The fact that there is an intermediate certificate in between your cert and the root CA trusted by the phone should not matter. This is how certificates are supposed to work. So the fact that you are getting this error message is baffling. Could you compare the serial numbers or fingerprints of the trusted root CA on the Yealink against the one listed by the cert utility? One other thing: Your server cert has expired in July, but I don't see how this could lead to the "not trusted" exception.

Answer (score 0):

I just read up on intermediate certificates (my memory failed during an earlier comment above) and I think I know what the problem is: Your phone already trusts the DigiCert root certificate at the top of the trust chain but neither your server nor your phone know anything about the intermediate cert, which the cert utility shows. You need to install the public key of the intermediate certificate on your server, too, in addition to the server certificate for which you have the private key. Here is a helpful link that explains the function of intermediate certs in more detail: [SSL Installing Intermediate Certificates](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=18923)

I quote:

> The intermediate certificate, or certificates, completes the chain to a root certificate trusted by the browser.  During SSL negotiation, the server sends the trust chain to the client to assist the client in building and verifying the trust chain.

The page also contains instructions on how to test whether the necessary intermediate certs are correctly installed on your web server.